# Using command line arguments when executing a BASH script

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I've created a script that removes all zero-length files from a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -size 0 -type f -exec rm -i '{}' \;
```

It works well, except that it only works in the directory the script is actually located in and its sub-directories. I want to be able to use a directory as a command line argument (*bash scriptname dirname*) while executing the script and have it only search **that** directory and it's sub-directories, not the actual directory the script is located in. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: hint: check what arguments `find` accepts and what `.` means

Answer (score 0):

With $x you can access the x-th command line argument of your bash script. So in your case this should be something like

```
 find $1 -size 0 -type f -exec rm -i '{}' \;
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Wouldn't $* by a better option than $1? Wouldn't that search all directories submitted as command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

In Bash you can pass argument to your script. These argument can be used using $ sign. For example:

```
./hello 123 abc xyz
```

here $0 is your program name
$1 is 123 and so on

You can pass values and use them in your program from $1 to $9.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of `find` accepts multiple paths, you can pass all the positional parameters like this:

```
find "$@" -size 0...
```

Note: you should not use $* for file names! it expands parameters into a string, so any file names with spaces or new lines in will break the command. "$@" preserves these, so is safe to use for this. If `find` doesn't accept multiple paths, you can loop over the parameters like this:

```
for dir in "$@"; do
    find "$dir" -size 0...
done
```